# Open or convert .cdr files?

Tags: 10.04, software-recommendation, file-format

I have a scanned image, and it's in Corel Draw (.cdr) format (~6mb). Is there a way to open it, or convert it to something that I can manage? I tried http://filespazz.com/ a few times, but it didn't work due to some timeout error.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try opening `.cdr` files with [Inkscape](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/inkscape/).

Comment: it opened in LibreOffice Draw 4.0.3 :)

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98315/open-corel-draw-files-on-debian

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to try imagemagick convert utility,Imagemagic can be easily installed using software center or synaptic.

Since the document is scanned it should be a bitmap which imagemagick can handle, only the version of the .cdr would be a concern, you did not mention the version of the cdr file so you may just try imagemagick, at your terminal in the directory where the .cdr file is located, run the convert utility like this;

```
convert image.cdr image.png
```

this will convert the .cdr image called image.cdr to a .png image called image.png file that you can easily use, probably vectorize by tracing in inkscape if you wish.

See the imagemagic [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) on the convert utility if more control over the output is needed. hope the output is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple and fast solution .cdr files could be open in libre office draw (actually it is default) Libre office draw has perfect save as for example to .png Than GIMP. Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308845/cdr-to-svg-convert-using-imagemagick/29630051#29630051).

> In order to work with CDR images you need to install some delegates
>   for ImageMagick. In order to convert CDR files you need to install
>   `uniconvertor` for CDR delegate:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-uniconvertor
> ```
>
> List of all delegates:
>
> ```
> convert -list delegate
> ```
>
> By default it outputs:
>
> ```
> cdr =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
> ```
>
> Then run:
>
> ```
> convert image.cdr -flatten -thumbnail '512x512' image.png
> ```
>
> Or with zoom cropping:
>
> ```
> convert image.cdr -flatten -thumbnail '512x512^' -gravity center -crop 512x512+0+0 +repage image.png
> ```
>
> I convert to .png here, but you may choose your own output format.

Comment: Why am I getting this error when running convert command? "ImportError: No module named sk1libs.utils.fs"